# update container values at the runtime in Azure Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

I have docker image/ACR running successfully in my AKS cluster.

Docker Image has configuration file with all credentials saved in it.
I want to change values of .config file at the time of kubernetes deployment creation.

I am using helm chart for deployment.
Do I need to mention these values in values.yaml file ?

How do I mention which file inside application needs to be updated with values from Azure key vault?

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Secrets Store CSI Driver for Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver) to use secrets from Azure Key Vault.

When you have an AKS and a ACR, why you need to specify credentials ? You can assign the Role "AcrPull" to the AKS identity and then the AKS is allows to pull images from your ACR.

Comment: I can successfully pull image’s in cluster. I want to update  app configuration values in my .config file running inside container at the deployment creation time in AKS.